# Post the form data to server using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have this html dashboard, and I want to submit this form data to server through api call in AngularJS. I am aware of creating a module, controller and link the controller to $http to post the data in to server. But in the the below code, i have found it is unusual as normal angularJS coding I have learned. Can someone suggest me How do i define my submitRequest() function of submit button in the controller and link it to $http..

```
 <form ng-controller="RequestController" method="post">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row" ng-submit>
    <p class="text-info">Please create request...</p>
    <!-- Left -->
    <div class="col-lg-2">

      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Request</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <!-- process type -->
          <div class="groups list list-inset">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="generic_process_id">Select process typ:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="generic_process_id" ng-model="request.approvalObject.generic_process_id" >

              <option value="1"  ng-show="true" >Simple Process</option>

              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Priority</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <!-- priority type -->
          <div class="groups list list-inset">
            <label>Select priority:</label><br>
            <div class="btn-group" ng-init="request.approvalObject.priority='1'">
              <label class="btn btn-info" ng-model="request.approvalObject.priority" uib-btn-radio="'1'" uncheckable>Low</label>
              <label class="btn btn-info" ng-model="request.approvalObject.priority" uib-btn-radio="'2'" uncheckable>High</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Center -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <!-- Description part-->
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Description</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="short_text">Subject:</label>
            <textarea placeholder="Subject name" ng-model="request.approvalObject.short_text" class="form-control" rows="1" id="short_text"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="long_text">Description:</label>
            <textarea placeholder="Explanatory description" ng-model="request.approvalObject.long_text" class="form-control" rows="10" id="long_text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <pre>{{request.approvalObject|json}}</pre>
        <pre>{{request.form|json}}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Right -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <!-- value part-->
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Value</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="groups list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="" name="value" ng-model="request.approvalObject.value"><b class="text-primary">{{request.approvalObject.value_currency}}</b>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="groups list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <select class="form-control" name="value_currency" ng-model="request.approvalObject.value_currency">

                </select>
            <!--  <input type="text" placeholder="Value currency" name="value_currency" ng-model="request.approvalObject.value_currency">-->
            </label>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div ng-show="secondApprover"  class="groups list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Value gate" name="value_gate" ng-model="request.approvalObject.value_gate"><b class="text-primary">  {{request.approvalObject.value_currency}}</b>
            </label>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Approver</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="groups list list-insert">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="First approver name" name="approver1_name" ng-model="request.approvalObject.approver1_name">
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- show second approver if process type != 1 -->
          <div ng-show="secondApprover"  class="groups list list-insert">
            <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Second approver name" name="approver2_name" ng-model="request.approvalObject.approver2_name" >
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <!-- Heading -->
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>Date</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Body -->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <!-- expiration date part -->
          <label>Select expiration date:</label>
          <pre>Selected Local time : <em>{{request.approvalObject.date_of_expiration | date: 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm' }}</em></pre>
          <pre>Selected UTC time   : <em>{{request.approvalObject.date_of_expiration|  date: 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm' : 'UTC' }}</em></pre>
          <div uib-datepicker ng-model="request.approvalObject.date_of_expiration" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="options"></div>
          <div uib-timepicker ng-model="request.approvalObject.date_of_expiration" class="well well-sm" timepicker-options="options"></div>

        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary center-block col-xs-3" ng-click='submitRequest()' style='margin: 450px;margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:100px'>Submit Request</button>
</form>
```

**`Controller.JS`**

```
 'use strict';

export default class RequestController {


  approvalObject = {};


  form = {};

  secondApprover = false;





$onInit() {
  this.approvalObject.generic_process_id=1;
  this.approvalObject.value_currency="EUR";
  this.approvalObject.priority=1;


  this.form.type=1;
}

  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor($http, $scope, socket) {
    this.$http = $http;
    console.log("testentry");
  }


  startApproval(approvalObject) {
    console.log("test");
    // creator_email and name from backend
    approvalObject.generic_process_id=1;
    approvalObject.creator_email= "test1@example.com";
    approvalObject.creator_name= "test1";
    approvalObject.approver1_email= approvalObject.approver1_name+"@example.com";
    approvalObject.approver2_email= approvalObject.approver2_name+"@example.com";

    // wip from backend
    approvalObject.approval_process_status= "wip";
    approvalObject.priority= "super high";
    //date_of_creation: '',  -->> filled by database
    approvalObject.date_of_expiration = undefined;
    approvalObject.sending_tool= "Web-App";
    approvalObject.submitRequest=true;


    this.$http.post('/api/approvals', approvalObject);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the API expecting to receive?

Comment: When i include 'approvalObject.submitRequest=true;' in the controller objects, then it should take the data input from the form as per my knowledge. But I am not sure if it is true...

Comment: Your template expects a submitRequest method to be implemented at the controller level. There's none present. Honestly, the whole thing looks to be quite a mess. You're mixing old style controlled based angular with 1.5 style component based development.

Comment: Yes, it is my task to be finished with older version angular which i am not familiar with And I got stucked how to proceed further..

Comment: Is it possible that can i write the code in two AngularJS versions in Single App?

Comment: Development styles from the older versions of Angular can be mixed with the more modern, component based approach introduced in 1.5, but 2 instances of Angular cannot be used on the same app. The issue really seems to be that a bunch of code has been written haphazardly without much understanding of how Angular works and how all of the pieces fit together. I'd really recommend you visit Codelord.net and check out his book on modernizing an angular app to 1.6. He also has a number of blog posts that should help you. Your code needs far too much debugging to get help here IMHO.